# Show Admin Panel pages on WordPress depending on User logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function below that hides the menus in the admin panel - Since I am the developer of this website, I don't want the admins of the company to see certain sections such a plugins, etc.. How would I make it so that let's say 'Show it to only user called "Test"'.

```
function remove_menus() {  
/* remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                 //Dashboard  
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts */
remove_menu_page( 'layerslider' );
remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
/* remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                //Media  
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages  
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments    
  remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users  
  remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools  
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings */
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
function remove_menus() {  

  $currentUserId = get_current_user_id();

  if ($currentUserId != your id) {

     remove_menu_page( 'layerslider' );
     ....
  }

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

So if it's not the desired user, remove pages.